# Add custom domain to dynamic subdomain in nextjs app deployed in vercel that already has custom domain

Tags: next.js, dns, cloudflare, vercel, custom-domain

I have deployed a Next.js app in Vercel that renders a subdomain based content and I have already linked my domain to that project.

Project Deploy URL: `*.mysite.com`

Here, If John opens `john.mysite.com`, it will render content for John's profile.
Same for Mary, `mary.mysite.com` renders Mary's content.

Now, I want to let John and Mary connect custom domain pointing their subdomain on my app, like `www.john.com` will display John's content on my website, same for Mary.

This is my DNS configuration on CLoudflare.
[image]

The subdomains are splitted into 3 parts and each part has their own Next.js project pointing to that subdomain.

1. *root domain* and *www* for landing page.
2. *app* subdomain for admin page, where users can create their subdomain based content.
3. remaining *all subdomains* are matched by user generated subdomain's content.

I want to know how do do this. Just like adding custom domain to blogspot blog, imagine `john.mysite.com` is default blogspot url and `www.john.com` is custom domain.

**Edit after answer:**

`john.com` is using CLoudflare nameservers and this is the current DNS configuration for `john.com`. I too tried all vercel ip shown above to test if any works and this is my current one.

```
| Type  | Name       | Content            |
|-------|------------|--------------------|
| A     | john.com   | 76.76.21.21        |
| CNAME | www        | john.mysite.com    |
| CNAME | *          | my-app.vercel.app  |
```

This is giving me this result for both `john.com` and `www.john.com` but `john.mysite.com` is correctly giving me John's profile.
[image]

Also, the deployment URL provided by vercel cannot be used to load user's profile, like the deployment URL `my-app.vercel.app` tries to render profile for user with id `my-site`, so only custom domain like `john.mysite.com` can be used to load user profiles.

**Edit 2:**

I added following dns records to `john.com` and result is same.

```
| NS    | mysite.com | ns1.vercel-dns.com |
| NS    | mysite.com | ns2.vercel-dns.com |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Next.js app deployed on Vercel that serves different content based on the subdomain (e.g., `john.mysite.com` and `mary.mysite.com`).
You want to map external custom domains (e.g., `www.john.com` and `www.mary.com`) to these subdomains.

```bash
                               ┌────────────────┐
                        ┌──────┤  Vercel Cloud  ├────────┐
                        │      └────────────────┘        │
                        │                                │
                        │                                │
              ┌───────────────────┐             ┌───────────────────┐
              │     *.mysite.com  │             │    Vercel DNS     │
              └───────────────────┘             └───────────────────┘
                │              │                    │             │
┌───────────────┴───┐ ┌────────┴─────────┐ ┌────────┴───────┐ ┌───┴──────────────┐
│ john.mysite.com   │ │ mary.mysite.com  │ │ ns1.vercel.com │ │ ns2.vercel.com   │
└───────────────────┘ └──────────────────┘ └────────────────┘ └──────────────────┘
         │                     │                    │                   │
         │                     │                    │                   │
┌────────┴───────┐     ┌───────┴────────┐  ┌────────┴───────┐   ┌───────┴─────────┐
│ www.john.com   │     │ www.mary.com   │  │  DNS Records   │   │   DNS Records   │
│ (Custom Domain)│     │(Custom Domain) │  │   for john.com │   │  for mary.com   │
└────────────────┘     └────────────────┘  └────────────────┘   └─────────────────┘
```

That would involve configuring DNS records to point custom domains to the Vercel-hosted subdomains, and potentially involves Vercel's support for custom domain configurations within their platform.

Based on "[Vercel / Adding & Configuring a Custom Domain](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/domains/add-a-domain)", you would need first to add a wildcard domain to your Vercel project:

- Go to your project's settings on the Vercel dashboard.
- Navigate to the Domains section.
- Enter `*.mysite.com` and add it as a wildcard domain. That will allow any subdomain of `mysite.com` to be directed to your Vercel project.

Then configure DNS settings for each custom domain:

- For an apex domain (like `john.com`), you need to configure it with an A record pointing to the IP address provided by Vercel.
- For a subdomain (like `www.john.com`), you should configure it with a CNAME record pointing to the alias Vercel provides for your deployment.

```
+------------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| Name             | Type  | Content                             |
+------------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| *.mysite.com     | CNAME | <vercel-alias-for-your-app>         |
+------------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| www.john.com     | CNAME | <vercel-alias-for-johns-subdomain>  |
+------------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| www.mary.com     | CNAME | <vercel-alias-for-marys-subdomain>  |
+------------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| mysite.com       | NS    | ns1.vercel-dns.com                  |
+------------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| mysite.com       | NS    | ns2.vercel-dns.com                  |
+------------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
```

If required, you might have to verify access to the domain, especially if it is already in use by another Vercel account. You would do this by adding a TXT record in your DNS settings.

You might consider using [Vercel Nameservers](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/domains/working-with-nameservers) (optional but recommended).
If you want to leverage Vercel's full CDN and performance benefits, you can change your domain's nameservers to Vercel's nameservers. In your domain registrar's panel, replace your current nameservers with those provided by Vercel.

Once you have configured the DNS settings or updated the nameservers, Vercel will verify the domain. It may take some time to propagate. After verification, the domain's status in your Vercel dashboard will update, confirming it is ready for use. See also "[How can I manage my Vercel DNS records? / Verifying DNS Records](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-manage-vercel-dns-records#verifying-dns-records)"

With this configuration, each of your users can have a custom domain that points to their respective subdomains on your Next.js app.
For example, `www.john.com` will display the content from `john.mysite.com`.

---

> 404: Not found

The issue you are seeing, where both `john.com` and `www.john.com` are leading to a 404 error, while `john.mysite.com` is correctly displaying John's profile, could be from DNS misconfiguration, propagation delays, or the domain not being correctly added to your Vercel project.

#### DNS Issues:

- The A record for `john.com` pointing to `76.76.21.21` should be correct if that is the IP address provided by Vercel for your deployment. However, Vercel generally recommends using an [`ALIAS`](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/alias-record/) or [`ANAME` record](https://knowledge.digicert.com/dnsme/managed-dns/aname-records) for root domains instead of an [`A` record](https://serverfault.com/a/820033/783) if your DNS provider supports it.
- The CNAME record for `www` is pointing to `john.mysite.com`, which might be incorrect if `www.john.com` is supposed to point to a Vercel deployment. It should point to your Vercel deployment URL or a Vercel-provided alias.
- The wildcard CNAME record is pointing to `my-app.vercel.app`, which would be correct if you are trying to capture all other subdomains.

For `john.com` using Cloudflare, you might try the following configuration:

```
| Type  | Name       | Content                     |
|-------|------------|-----------------------------|
| A     | john.com   | IP provided by Vercel       |
| CNAME | www        | Alias provided by Vercel    |
```

#### Vercel Deployment Issues:

- Make sure `john.com` and `www.john.com` are added to your Vercel project under the ["Domains" section](https://vercel.com/docs/getting-started-with-vercel/domains). Vercel needs to know about these domains to route them correctly.
- Vercel's deployment needs to be configured to handle requests coming from `john.com` and `www.john.com`. That can involve custom domain setup within your Vercel project settings.

If Vercel provides an `ANAME` or `ALIAS` record for root domains, use that instead of an `A` record for `john.com`.

- In your Vercel project settings, add `john.com` and `www.john.com` as custom domains. That may involve a verification step.
- Sometimes, redeploying your application can help Vercel recognize the newly added custom domains.

#### Regarding NS Records:

The NS records you added to `john.com`:

```
| NS    | mysite.com | ns1.vercel-dns.com |
| NS    | mysite.com | ns2.vercel-dns.com |
```

That configuration appears incorrect because you are setting NS records for `mysite.com` within the DNS configuration for `john.com`. [NS records](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-ns-record/) are intended to delegate DNS management for a domain to another server, and should be used at the registrar level, not in the domain's DNS configuration. If `john.com` is using Cloudflare, it should retain Cloudflare's NS records.

- If you are not moving your entire DNS management to Vercel, remove the NS records you added for `mysite.com` from the `john.com` DNS settings.
- Go to your Vercel project settings, check that the custom domains have been added, and follow the verification process.
- Use tools like `dig` or `nslookup`, or online services like [DNS Checker](https://dnschecker.org/), to verify that your DNS records are propagating correctly.

Comment: @BibekOli I cannot do direct conversation, but do edit your question with what you have done, and what is still not working. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @BibekOli I have edited the answer to address your edit.

Comment: adding domain in vercel project is necessary to make it work, (I think you didn't mention it previously). thanks for your help. It solved my confusion since long time. and for vercel alias, the custom domain too works e.g. `john.mysite.com`

Comment: @BibekOli Great, well done! Don't hesitate to edit my answer to make it clearer, based on your experience. I will validate your edits.